# Idiom for addressing the most important point

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms

What's an idiom for getting right to the most important point?

Someone clever/wise always gets right to the heart of the matter. An educator who understands their audience perfectly and always says exactly what needs to be said when it needs to be said. An educator who knows exactly what issues their audience is having without needing to be told, and gets right on with addressing those issues.

Something like "stabbing at the heart of the matter."

Comment: [cut to the chase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_to_the_chase)

Answer (score 1):

**Get down to brass tacks**

> to start talking about the most important or basic facts of a situation:

*Let's get down to brass tacks. Who's paying for all this?*

Another idiom you could use is *get down to the **nitty-gritty.***

> the basic facts of a situation:

*Let's get down to the nitty-gritty - how much will it cost?*

[Cambridge Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to what you're describing and I am not sure you can combine them in the same idiom.

1. You say

> someone who understands their audience perfectly and always says exactly what needs to be said when it needs to be said.

That's the definition of being ***to the point***:

> expressing something very important or suitable for the subject being discussed:
>
> - Her comments on my work were very apt and to the point. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to-the-point))

[Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+the+point) elaborates a bit more:

> 1. Relevant, concerning the matter at hand, as in
>
> - ***Her remarks were brief and to the point*** [Early 1800s] For an antonym, see *beside the point*.
>
> 2. Concerning the important or essential issue. This usage is often put as ***come*** or ***get to
>    the point*** , meaning *address the important issue*. For example,
>
> - ***Please
>   come to the point; we haven't much time***, or
> - ***Do you suppose he'll ever
>   get to the point of all this?*** [Late 1300s]

2. But the quality of character of *getting straight to the point* is pretty well expressed by a phrase you use:

***get/cut to the heart of the matter*** or ***cut to the crux of the matter***

> The essential point or problem is ***the crux***. People are always trying
> to ***get to the crux of a matter*** or ***the crux of a problem***, while others
> try to distract them.
>
> The noun ***crux*** is often followed by the phrases "of the matter" or "of
> the problem." When people are trying to identify the crux of
> something, it's like they want to ***get to the heart of it***. They want to
> peel back the layers and find out what something is really all about
> or what is causing the problem. No more beating around the bush! ([Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/crux))

Crux is defined by [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crux)

> the most important or serious part of a matter, problem, or argument.

Other variants include: [Get to the nub of the matter](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-nub-of-the-problem-matter-argument-etc), or [get down to the nuts and bolts](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+down+to+the+nuts+and+bolts)